# adapter in fragment - android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

so now we've got a

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_style, RowBean_data);
ListView lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in fragment, we want it to show a list with items and text.

Right now we're getting an error with the following code: http://pastebin.com/BV9X6Dys

The other classes:

> CustomAdapter.java http://pastebin.com/eA5Xx1Ng
>
> MainActivity.java [pastebin.com/Nv1Zip11](http://pastebin.com/Nv1Zip11)
>
> HomeFragment.java [pastebin.com/8DiXQHsy](http://pastebin.com/8DiXQHsy)

How can we make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting `Context` to `Activity`.

The error is here..

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
```

So the solution is to use the `context` to get the inflator service, like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Another alternate way is that like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Like @Zharf said

### EDIT

Also I think that passing `getActivity()` to the CustomAdapter's constructor is enough.

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_style, RowBean_data);
```

Comment: Alternative method (which I prefer) to get `LayoutInflater`: `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);`

Comment: @krzk Happy to help. :)

Comment: THANKS!!!! I used LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); and it works for me!!